# Docker can't find requirements.txt even though it is present in the same folder as the dockerfile and there is no typo

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, requirements.txt

I have a docker file and I am trying to build the image but it can't find requirements.txt:

[Project struture, docker file and cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzVii.png)

Here are the contents of dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/src
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

The error I am getting:

```
ERROR [3/6] COPY requirements.txt ./                                                                                                                         0.0s
[3/6] COPY requirements.txt ./:
failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found
```

I tried this:

```
COPY requirements.txt /app
WORKDIR /app
```

but it didn't work either

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... directly in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. While you are at it, take a few minutes to understand how the editor window works and format your code correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just a path issues. Example structure:

```
/myapp
  /src
    main.py
  Dockerfile
  requirements.txt
```

Try this:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY src/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/src
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Docker uses a layering system, which caches intermediate images to make building faster. If files (`requirements.txt`) change frequently, it's more efficient to copy those files as late as possible in the Dockerfile to avoid invalidating the cache for steps that haven't changed.

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# First copy the source code. The assumption here is that source code will change less frequently 
# than your requirements.txt file. This lets Docker cache the installed packages to make 
# subsequent builds faster
COPY src/ .

# Next, copy over the requirements.txt file. This is done after copying source code to leverage Docker layer caching
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define the command to run your app using CMD which defines your runtime
# Here we use the uvicorn ASGI server, with settings for host and port
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```